# git fsck --lost-found, как восстановить данные

Tags: git, git-reset

После неосторожной команды 'git reset --hard' решил восстановить потерянные изменения. Вычитал про команду `git fsck --lost-found`, применил. Получил результат:

```
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (58982/58982), done.
dangling commit a02ec0428464124e0ea54d60a43484645cc2ffe9
dangling commit bd843215757dff48cff932319cd264f449806647
dangling blob b29eaed79e50ef2a0207391d18729f1f4e84e346
dangling blob c1b5605c796983423d45ae53ee914ce7bb1534a1
dangling commit fc49695f084d2b4858f0b848e93499fd1d42fe5f
dangling commit 74d49538359b8fb78030af576d39215073d2c91e
```

А что дальше? Как найти свои изменения?

Comment: Для начала стоило бы посмотреть git reflog

Comment: А в чем их отличия?

Comment: Рефлог - это история конкретной ветки. А fsck - огромная свалка несортированного мусора.

Comment: git reflog помог восстановить то, что нужно )